# Cannot Login using Spring security facebook in Grails

Tags: facebook, grails, authentication, spring-security

I am using the spring security facebook plugin to implement login in my grails application. I am using the 0.14.5 version of spring security facebook plugin. It was working fine until couple of months ago, now I cannot login to my application. I get the following error:

```
2014-12-12 16:52:50,197 [http-bio-8080-exec-1] ERROR [/testApp].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/testApp] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
Message: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode
    Line | Method
->>  175 | findClass                 in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    423 | loadClass                 in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    147 | loadClass . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
|    356 | loadClass                 in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   2451 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
|   1810 | getDeclaredMethods        in     ''
|     46 | getLocked . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference
|     33 | get                       in     ''
|     59 | create . . . . . . . . .  in testApp.user.FacebookAuthService
|    118 | create                    in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.DefaultFacebookAuthDao
|     67 | authenticate . . . . . .  in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthProvider
|     40 | attemptAuthentication     in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthRedirectFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I tried to upgrade the plugin but that did not help. During debuggin I found that I was getting access token from facebook and the error was occurring in following line

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
```

Comment: why don't you use `OAuth` plugin with `facebook` addon?

Comment: Changing it to OAuth would take too long! The most interesting thing about this is that this was working about couple of months ago, it stopped working all of sudden without any change to the code!